# How to make nginx support mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, nginx

I have install php5-mysql in my server.
But when I use function mysql_connect ,it's no working .
and I wrote these code to Test.It's said unavailable

```
<?php
if ( function_exists("mysql_connect")){
  echo "support";
}else{

 echo "unavailable";
}
?>
```

How can I configuration my ubuntu server to support php connect mysql??

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you remember to restart nginx after installing?

Comment: Is that a yes or a no?

Comment: show your `phpinfo();`

Comment: @pamelus I have showed

Comment: @Epodax It seems no working

Comment: Is there any 'mysql' string in your phpinfo?

Comment: @pamelus  I have add the picture

Comment: I restart my ubuntu server,and "spawn-fcgi -a 127.0.0.1 -p 9000 -C 10 -u www-data -f /usr/bin/php-cgi" It's working ,thanks